# Can't justify single line of text inside a flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, text-align, justify

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="line">
            1. Some text before a placeholder
            <div class="placeholder">
                placeholder text
            </div>
            text after placeholder.
        </div>

        <div class="line">
              2. Line which doesn't have any placeholders and a lot of text.
        </div>
        
        <div class="line">
          <div class="content">
             3. Putting text inside a div to apply flew-grow on pure text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut viverra tellus. Cras rutrum turpis vitae justo gravida, sit amet semper leo feugiat. Nullam sed blandit libero, ultricies accumsan leo. Etiam fringilla placerat velit, quis ullamcorper purus convallis vitae. Vestibulum ultrices accumsan fringilla. Nulla luctus rhoncus magna, vel mattis eros convallis in. Ut vel pellentesque odio.
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.line {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;
}

.placeholder {
    flex-grow: 1;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 0 5px;
    text-align-last: center;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cazfxdpt/)

I have a container `line`, which displays its items using `flex`. Its children are a mixture of pure text and any number of placeholders.

For lines that do have placeholders i.e. line 1, `flex-grow` will expand the placeholders so that the whole line is justified.

For lines that are just pure text i.e. line 2, since it's inside a `flex` container, the `text-align` properties do not work. `justify-content` does not work either as there aren't any really "items" inside that container.

I thought about putting pure text inside an additional `div` so that I can apply `flex-grow` to it, which is shown in line 3. Unfortunately for this case I do not want the last line to be justified. This is also not an implementation I can likely go with.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the text into div, or probably semantically preferable p (Paragraphs) is a good idea and you should do that.

If o you want the last line to behave differently from the other, you should use a :last-child selector in your css.

Does that help?

Comment: That does not help as there is only one item in the container. `last-child` doesn't work as the text simply wraps to the next line so it's just one whole block of text and not multiple elements of text.